# Ionic hybrid app with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, hybrid-mobile-app, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to develop a proof of concept on a mobile hybrid application, our main target is apple iphone and android.

Now, I am kind of good with how to develop ionic pages and display data from ASP.NET Web API. We do not use cloud services (yet), so the Question is can a hybrid mobile app communicate with our dmz app servers where ASP.NET Web API is hosted ?. I feel there shouldn't be any issues, I couldn't find any material that confirms it.

Where ever i try to learn about ionic mobile apps using visual studio and cordova one or the other way it uses Azure mobile services or some other services from Azure, I couldn't find anything that confirms my thought and that is why i am not sure if i should move forward with my POC.

Comment: I'm not familar with dmz server. Normally, if the client side can get connected to your  server. The hybrid mobile app can communicate with your server by consuming ASP.NET Web API.

Comment: @venu Services from Azure have nothing to do with you hosting the web API on your DMZ server and trying to consume it. So, you can keep aside the Azure part and carry on as usual.

Comment: Cool... thank you..